# How can I fix User and Models issue?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a project and I have 2 issues.

In models.py I have:

```
from django.db import models
from children.models import Child
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class OrderLineItem(models.Model):
    order= models.ForeignKey("Order", null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order")
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    donation = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}".format(
            self.donation, self.child.name)
class Order(models.Model):
    full_name = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    town_or_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    street_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    street_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    orderlineitem = models.ForeignKey(OrderLineItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orderlineitem")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.id, self.date, self.full_name)
```

In the checkout html I have:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="payment-form" action="{% url 'checkout' %}">
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>

    <div id="credit-card-errors" style="display: none;">
        <div id="alert-message block-message error" id="stripe-error-message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ order_form | as_bootstrap }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ payment_form | as_bootstrap }}
    </div>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
    </div>
</form>
```

There are 2 issues:
1. I can't in the full_name onle the current user, but all users
2. It only allows me one order per user, meaning if I try to place another order with the same user I get this error: Order with this Full name already exists.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Neither of these issues are demonstrated by the code you have posted, and the traceback seems to indicate a completely separate third issue to do with saving in your view, for which you have not posted the code.

Comment: I will add now the views, however it was working before I changed the models to try to add the orderlineitem as a foreign key.